# Is Passing DOM Nodes through a Vue Prop bad practice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am currently in the process of writing a Carousel component and am trying to decide on the best method of implementation.

See the following component:

```
<template>

    <!-- Carousel -->
    <div class="carousel-container">

        <div ref="carousel" class="carousel">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>

        <carousel-navigation v-if="items.length" :orientation="orientation" :container="$refs.carousel" :items="items"></carousel-navigation>

    </div>

</template>

<script>

    import CarouselNavigation from 'core-js/components/common/CarouselNavigation';

    export default {

        components: {
            'carousel-navigation': CarouselNavigation
        },

        props: {

            orientation: {
                type: String,
                required: false,
                default: 'horizontal',
                validator: (value) => {
                    return ['horizontal', 'vertical'].indexOf(value) !== -1;
                }
            }

        },

        data() {
            return {
                items: []
            }
        },

        mounted () {
            this.items = [...this.$refs.carousel.children];
        }

    }

</script>
```

The `carousel-navigation` component accepts various props, but specifically `items` and `container`.

The `container` prop is expected to be a single DOM node, and the `items` prop is expected to be an array of DOM nodes.

The reason I need to pass DOM nodes is because the `carousel-navigation` needs to know where to scroll to (`items`) and what to scroll (`container`).

Is this bad practice? If so, what would be a better way to achieve this?

Comment: It doesn't look good. I'd expect a container to be a component that is responsible for manipulating its DOM.

Comment: @EstusFlask hmmm, The issue I have is that `carousel-navigation` needs to be a separate component as it can be used independently of the `carousel`, and the `carousel-navigation` needs to have some sort of way to tell the carousel where to navigate. I guess I could use events instead...

Comment: @EstusFlask - the more I think about your suggestion, the more I think you are right! The `carousel` component should be responsible for the manipulating of the elements within it. The carousel navigation should simply be a separate event firing component

Comment: *as it can be used independently of the carousel* - the question doesn't explain that. If you're trying to decouple carousel container and navigation, there could be better ways. That you're trying to pass a node indicates that something went wrong in how components were designed. That's why I'd consider this bad practice, not because it's bad per se. If you already have an idea how this can be solved in a better way, consider posting a self-answer, this could help somebody with the same problem.

Comment: @EstusFlask - of course! Whilst you are there, and to save me posting a separate question (happy to if you think it will help others), is there a way to select an element by query selector scoped within that component? e.g. `.carousel` but only within the component. The reason why I need this is because I am using a `scroll` library to navigate the carousel and it does not accept DOM nodes, instead, it requires a selector string. To save me doing a pull request on the library, is there a way I can get a selector for just `.carousel` in this component?

Comment: I didn't deal with this problem in Vue so I'd suggest to ask a new one for Vue-specific solution. Generally this means that you need to generate unique class name or id you can use in a selector. A proper way would be to make the lib accept DOM nodes, it's always frustrating when only selectors are accepted in a case like that.

Comment: @EstusFlask - Agreed! generating unique class names is the last resort, horribly dirty fix... I think I will opt for a pull request